# How to display system progress and hide splash screen in RHEL 6.2

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6

I had to force a hardware reboot due to some CPU hungry application. It now hangs at the start-up screen right after the progress circle completes.

I have no way to see what it is doing (checking the FS or something) but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, a s/w reboot occurs in 5 seconds.

How can I see the regular Linux start-up log instead of the splash screen and at least understand what it is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In /boot/grub/grub.conf, comment out the "splashimage" line. Then, in /etc/sysconfig/init, change the BOOTUP line to say "BOOTUP=verbose". That should restore the old-style text boot messages.